# Spotfire how to control one document property with another one with ironpython script

Tags: ironpython, spotfire

I have two document properties in form of a list boxes. The challenage is that when i select value 'last month' on the 1st document proeprty (named L8WLM), i want 2nd document property (named EmTime) to automatically change to 'Year&month' selection.
I'm trying to add this script below to act on property change but it doesnt work.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

```
if Document.Properties['L8WLM'] == 'last month':
    Document.Properties['EmTime'] = 'Year&month'
else:
    Document.Properties['EmTime'] = 'Week'
```

Comment: Your code seems fine to me. What is the error you get when you press "on" in iron python scripting?

Comment: solved! the issue was not with the ironpython script but with the property expression and display name, i changed both of them to be one word 'last_month' and then it worked, anyway thanks for looking into it @k88

Comment: Karolina, next time you encounter a similar issue, please do include the entire exact error message in your question :)